# Vim: swapping 2 characters in operation-pending mode

Tags: vim, key-bindings, remap

Using an exotic keyboard layout, I have to remap g (among others) which is, on my layout, in the h position on a classic qwerty layout. To do so I decided to swap g with h with the following commands:

```
noremap g h
noremap h g
```

This doesn't work. For instance typing hh is viewed as gh and not gg. Also when hitting g it shows g (with `showcmd` enabled) and not h and it doesn't seem to take the remapping into account, it act like the g command. But when hitting g again or waiting 1 second it actually moves left.

I tried the following to make it work in operation-pending mode

```
onoremap g h
onoremap h g
```

but it doesn't change anything.

So why does it behaves that way? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with multi-key commands like `gg` (or the various `<C-w>` commands from which I remember a similar issue) is that they are *not* the `g` command followed by a `g` operator. (Especially with the `g` prefix, there's a whole range of unrelated commands not found in the original vi in that space.)

I'm afraid you'll have to define separate remappings for all of them:

```
:nnoremap hh gg
...
```

Comment: Well that's a shame. And although it sort of answers the question, it doesn't explain the behaviour I described (the g remap that doesn't work even in normal mode) which is the most annoying. Thanks anyway.